# How to change text in camera access permission prompt with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, permissions

I need to add an explanation of why my app is asking permission for camera use.

How to change the text to whatever I want?

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: No, for security reason the browser wants the user to know that the browser itself is asking the question, and not the web application requesting access. Bad people could change the question so that it deceived people.

Comment: Just modify your website to give its own explanation inside the site itself of why it needs camera access.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Now I got an idea why we don't have access to this prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the text of that browser prompt- or any browser permissions prompt. Those permissions prompts are there for security reasons. As stated by [@Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) in the comments, if people could change it, bad actors would change it to trick people into granting permissions by editing the prompt to say something misleading.

A webpage can only query for whether the user has granted it certain permissions using [the Permissions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions).

If you want to let your users know *why* your website wants that permission and what it was use it for, just do it in your website itself. What you can do is show an explanation in your website and hide it once the permission has been given (query via the Permissions API) or once the explanation has been dismissed (if you give it a button to dismiss it).